# SAS Do loops: use loop variable inside the loop to create lagged variables

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to create variables containing lagged values of a given variable for a large number of lags. How could I do this? I try the following:

```
data out; 
set in;
do i = 1 to 50;
%let j = i;
lag_&j = Lag&j.(x);
end;
run;
```

How can I get the loop variable `i` into the macro variable `j` or how to use it directly to create the appropriately named variable and for the Lag function?

Comment: If you have SAS/ETS license look into proc expand as well.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I now have even more than one way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris J answers the question, but here i'll provide my preferred way of doing this.

```
%macro lagvar(var=,num=);
  %do _iter = 1 %to &num.;
    lag_&_iter. = lag&_iter.(&var.);
  %end;
%mend lagvar;

data out;
  set in;
  %lagvar(var=x,num=50); *semicolon optional here;
run;
```

This is a more modular usage of the macro loop (and more readable, assuming you use intelligent names - the above is okay, you could do even more with the name if you wanted to be very clear, and of course add comments).

Comment: This is a perfect example for this approach.  Good tip.

Comment: I think I'd do the same because one typically needs to employ the same solution in more than one place. @Joe You might need to change  `lag_&iter. =` to `lag_&_iter. =`

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing macro & datastep syntax incorrectly...

You need a macro-loop (`%DO` instead of `do`) to generate the datastep code (i.e. lag1-lag50), and macro-loops need to be within a macro.

```
%MACRO LAGLOOP ;
  data out ;
    set in ;
    %DO J = 1 %TO 50 ;
      lag_&J = lag&J(x) ;
    %END ;
  run ;
%MEND ;
%LAGLOOP ;
```